# DITA and XSL-FO wrong rendering border

Tags: xsl-fo, dita

I have generated xsl-fo like that:
http://pastebin.com/mQJq6tyB

It is basically note placed in `<dd>` tag (in dita file). The problem is, that when this is rendered it has additional border lines rendered on text, when text is longer than 3 lines. When I try render the same note outside of `<dlentry>` completely, it is rendering fine.

Maybe I missed something in the styles, and I cannot see what could cause it (although I checked this couple times, and I didn't saw anything strange), or maybe its a some problem with xsl-fo itself? Or Dita-OT2.0.1? I have no idea really, and thats why I wanted to ask.

I am using org.dita.pdf2 plugin, but also my own plugin which overwrites some styles.

Oh - and lines are over the text "...tijdelijk..." in the example.

[image]

Comment: Oh right, and I am talking about PDF output.

Comment: Which FO formatter are you using?  Using Antenna House and pasting your fragment into a sample FO document, the only lines that I get are the top and bottom borders on the `fo:block` containing your 'tijdelijk' text.  Can you provide a screenshot of what's gone wrong?

Comment: Since I was self-trained with XSL-FO and DITA and I get the project in the middle (so I didn't set up this from the begining) I still have problem to answer questions like that. Basically I am using DITA OT 2.0.1, but I am not sure if thats what you asking. If not, please point me the place I can found it. 

I added image. As you can see my problem was part of the bigger file. Although I choosed the only fragment which could cause it. I know that because when I removed <dlentry> completely and place note outside, everytjing was awesome.

Can I add something else to help you help me?

Comment: That is from using Apache FOP. RenderX XEP and Antennahouse both format correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be a bug in Apache FOP. If you wish to try and workaround this, move the border-bottom-* and border-top-* attributes to the table-cell and not the block inside the table cell.

```
        <fo:table-cell start-indent="0pt" padding-bottom="5pt" padding-top="5pt" text-align="justify" border-bottom-style=" solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-bottom-color=" #000000" padding="1.9pt" border-top-style=" solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-top-color=" #000000" >
        <fo:block font-family="helveticaNeueLTStdThinIt" font-size="10pt" padding-top="3pt" padding-bottom="2pt" margin-top="3pt" margin-bottom="3pt" page-break-inside="avoid" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-after="avoid" 
            margin-left="2cm" >
            <fo:inline start-indent="0cm">
                <fo:inline float="left" clear="both" height="20px" margin-top="0px" padding-left="0cm" margin-left="0px" page-break-before="avoid" page-break-after="avoid"/>
            </fo:inline>tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk  tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk tijdelijk  </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
```

Is closer to what you desire. You would need to adjust spacing accordingly. Or put a table inside that cell and borders on it.

[image]

Comment: Sadly not possible in my case. I mean - everything is possible, but this won't be good solution for me. Anyway its good to know that this is a bug.